# Check if user typed specific string with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, if-statement

To simplify my question using the statement below, how can I have my javascript always print to console what the user typed?

A blip from my code

```
if (userTyped === 'getname '+ variable) {
```

Where 'variable' will always equal whatever last half of the string they typed. For example, if a user types "getname 398502" then log it to the console, or if a user types "getname 598024" then log that to the console.

So as long as they typed 'getname ' then print all of what they typed.

Comment: `if (userTyped === 'getname ' + variable) {` ?

Comment: Perhaps validate the command with a regular expression, and use capture groups for the command arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to make sure `'getname '` is at the start of your string:

```
if (userTyped.indexOf('getname ') === 0) {
    console.log(userTyped);
}
```

Comment: I probably explained myself poorly, but this has proven the solution for me! Danke everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to validate the command and extract the argument.  Something like:

```
var input = 'getname 19395029'; //Sample input
var re = /^getname (\d+)$/g;
var match = re.exec(input);
if(match) // Input matches command format
    window.alert('Getting name: ' + match[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if( /^getname /i.test( input ) ) { 
    console.log( input.replace( /^getname /i, "" ) ); 
}
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/epDSN/)

Answer (score 0):

> can equal anything the user typed

Then you don't want to test against a variable (with a certain value). Instead, you want to test the first part against `'getname'` and parse the second part into a variable. You can do that using [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), for example:

```
var match = userTyped.match(/^getname (\d+)$/);
if (match) {
    var variable = match[1]; // maybe parseInt(match[1], 10) ?
}
```